# Object(...) is not a function in React Natiive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I try to make a change of views, I'm relying on a video that I've seen on YouTube and when I implement it in my project for some reason it doesn't work. What I want to do is a change of sight, but trying gives me a strange error: "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" and I don't know how to fix the problem
App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import AppContainer from './routes'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppContainer/>
   
  );
}
export default App;
```

routes.js

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigation } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import LoginScreen from './components/LoginScreen'
import DashboardScreen from './components/dashboardScreen'
import AuthLoadingScreen from './components/authLoadingScreen'


const BeforeSignin = createStackNavigation({
    Login: {
        screen: LoginScreen
    },

}, {
    headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "Login"

})

const AfeterSignin = createStackNavigation({
    Dashboard: {
        screen: DashboardScreen
    },

}, {
    headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "Dashboard"
})

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigation({
    Auth: BeforeSignin,
    App: AfeterSignin, 
    AuthLoadingScreen: AuthLoadingScreen

  
}, { 
    eaderMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "Auth"

})

export default  createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

error
[image: Error]

Comment: it seems like import/export problem. Can you share working example on codepen or etc. ?

Comment: what version of react-navigation you have ?

Comment: The version is  4.4.3